# One system consisting of multiple linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

Hello everyone i apologize if this has been answered before i honestly couldnt find it. The problem im having is that im trying to Define one system with multiple equations something like this:

```
s1[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
ax1 - ax2 - ax3 + ax4 + ax5 - ax6 + ax7 + ax8 + ax9 == a

s2[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
ax1 - ax2 - ax3 - ax5 + ax6 + ax7 + ax8 - ax9 == a  //a is an arbitrary number
.
.
.
s9[.....] := ....

system1 = {s1[ ...], s2[ ...], s3[ ...], s4[ ...], s5[ ...], 
s6[ ...], s7[ ...], s8[ ...], s9[ ...]}

answer = Solve[{system1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}]
```

but doing this i get this error "{s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9} is not a quantified system of equations \
and inequalities." 
anyone knows the proper way of defining multiple equations with one system? Thank you.

Comment: You have one == in definition of each equation and another when you join them? Also, what is your exact system anyways? All of them equal to an `a` with exactly same coefficients? At least for `s`1 and `s2` it seems so... In that case you only have one independent equation?

Comment: that == was me trying different things "a" is just an arbitrary number

Comment: im guessing im trying to define a system of mulitple linear equations under a single variable ? is that possible? i dont know if im making sense here lol

Comment: You might wanna take a look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingLinearSystems.html

Comment: thank you for trying  Behzad Nazari i appreciate it. new to the whole wolfram world its a little hard to communicate my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i got it. if it helps any beginner here's is what i was trying to do.

```
 system = {6 x1 - 20 x2 - 6 x3 + 16 x4 + 14 x5 - 8 x6 + 5 x7 + x8 + 
           13 x9 == 16 && 5 x1 - 15 x2 - 13 x3 - 5 x5 + 14 x6 + 7 x7 + 14 x8 - 15 x9 ==15&&.......}

answer = Solve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}]
```